# How to check if DB is up & running from Application Server?

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, monitor

I am looking for a good approach to check if Oracle Database is up and running from Unix server.

Few options which I have thought are,

1. Write a shell script in App server which connects to DB. Trigger a
   dummy select statement. If that works then DB is up.
2. Write a shell script in App server which pings the DB. If ping works
   then DB is up.

Are there any other efficient approaches? What are the pros-cons in the above approaches?

Comment: Go for the first solution. Simple `ping` does not check if DB is running at all. `tnsping` does not check if DB is running either. tnsping just checks if the Oracle Listener is working but not the database.